# Master Pages Controls Id After Rendered

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

In my asp.net projects there is a master page and there is  a control on Contentplaceholder1. Changing this control's id after rendered like "ctl00_Contentplaceholder1_control" in my local. But at the server its changing like "Contentplaceholder1_control". When i used `documents.getelelentbyid('ctl00_Contentplaceholder1_control')` js function, its working on my local but not working at the server. So why disappearing "ctl00_" when app  runs at the server?

Edit:

Why doesn't the server side control id  contains "ctl00_" after rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Use the server side property `ClientID` to get the appropriate ID or if you are using .NET 4, use `ClientIDMode`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ClientIDMode to make static IDs? Which version of .NET Framework are you using?

Another options (for older versions) is to wrap your .NET control in a div with static id, then use jQuery like this:

```
 var wrapper = $('#wrapperDivId');
 var control = wrapper.find('typeOfControl')[0];
```

This way, no matter of how your control's id is rendered, you can always have access to it.

For example, TextBoxes render to `<input type='text' />`. Now you can wrap your text box inside a div like this:

```
 <div id='wrapper'>
      <asp:TextBox ID='firstName' runat='server' />
 </div>
```

Now, no matter of the client id, you can get your textbox at client side using:

```
 $('#wrapper input')
```

Comment: I'm using .Net framework 3.5. I didn't try it yet, i'll try it. But i must say that This control is iframe which is in an usercontrol, and its opening like pop up. Is it possible the use ClientIDMode ?

Comment: No, ClientIDMode is new to .NET 4. It's not in version 3.5. I suggest wrapping the control. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do like...

```
documents.getElelentbyid('<%=ControlID.ClientID %>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("<%= control.ClientID %>");
```

that is much safer and better approach than hard-coding client id.

Comment: Control is an iframe which is in an usercontrol. User control is opening like a pop up. And when i select something in this pop up its changing somethings on the pages. And when i use the "<%= control.ClientID %>" there is another bug. It says you can't changes blah blah...

Comment: you have to replace your 'control' with server side ID of the control. To go any further you would have to provide more code for us to better understand the structure.

Comment: Why doesn't the server side control id  contains "ctl00_" after rendered?

Answer (score 0):

[Answer is here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

My hosting server changed their asp.net servers to asp.net 4 server. So my controls rendered without "ctl00_". I compiled my .net 3.5 project to the .net 4 and [I changed web.config file like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/image_000FDA40.png).

Now its working.